# How to deploy differential script of Database using Database Project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I am wokring with Database project in Visual Studio specifically for deployment purpose. I have got it all working but issue is that when I publish (directly on database or generate a script) it generates the script of complete database regardless of the script change. This takes a lot of time to deploy as we have a large number of objects in database. Is there a way to just publish the differential? Like any thing that is changed since last version, only that should be published.